# Change upper case to lower case and vice versa without using functions and if statements

Tags: c, performance, function, if-statement

I have a problem in C:

I can't figure out how to change upper case to lower case and vice versa, without using if statements, functions, and not changing characters other than letters.

A solution to this problem is very useful to limited resource systems.

Comment: There are numerous possible solutions - what have you tried so far ?

Comment: The "limited resource system" is so limited that it can't even run an `if` statement?

Comment: I think this is homework or an interview question. Designed to think about ASCII and hex representation and bit operations.

Comment: DrKoch - Solution to this question was marked as may be useful for µC, at basic course of C language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
c ^= ((c>='A' && c <= 'Z') || (c>='a' && c <= 'z')) << 5
```

... but I'm not really sure it's better for resource-limited systems than using 'if' etc.

Comment: You assume that a boolean expression is converted to integer 1 if true and 0 if false. Is this assumption correct ? Isn't this undefined ?

Comment: @chmike: Yes, that is guaranteed by the C standard. I also assume that the character set is ASCII, which is not guaranteed by the standard - but if the system is so resource-constrained that it can't afford an `if`, it's probably reasonable to assume a particular character set :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because 'A' is 0x41 and 'a' is 0x61 you could just XOR the bit 0x20.

```
0x61 ^ 0x20 == 0x41  /* a -> A */
0x41 ^ 0x20 == 0x61  /* A -> a */
```

In a loop for a complete string `char *s` (assuming it contains just letters):

```
for (; *s; s++) *s ^= 0x20;
```

---

**EDIT**

We should apply this to letters only. 'A' is 0x41. 'Z' is 0x5A, lower case chars are just upper_case_char + 0x20.

So `c & 0xDF` is always the upper case version of a character.

The obfuscated test looks like this:

```
 for (; *s; s++) *s ^= ((*s & 0xDF) >= 0x41 && (*s & 0xDF) <= 0x5A) 
                    ? 0x20 : 0x00;
```

or equivalent and slightly more readable:

```
 for (; *s; s++) *s ^= ((*s & 0xDF) >= 'A' && (*s & 0xDF) <='Z') 
                    ? 0x20 : 0x00;
```

Comment: Good explanation. However, the questions asks to exclude non-letters. `((c>='A' && c <= 'Z') || (c>='a' && c <= 'z'))` evaluates to `1` for letters (A-z, a-z) and `0`for other characters. Factor that in (i.e. by multplying the `0x20` with it) to complete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
void changecase (char * s)
{
    for (; *s; s++)
        *s ^= ((*s>='A') && (*s<='Z') || (*s>='a') && (*s<='z'))?32:0;
}
```

If you don't like the ternary or the comparison operators:

```
void changecase (char * s)
{
    for (; *s; s++)
        *s ~= (
               /* check top bits are 0100 or 0110 */
               ((*s & 0xE0 ^ 0x80) - 0x40) & 0x100) &&
               /* not codes 64 or 96 */
               (*s & 0x1f) &&
               /* first 26 from 64 onwards only */
               !(((*s && 0x1f) - 27) & 0x100)
              ) <<5;
}
```

Comment: An argument could be made that the ternary is equivalent to an if statement, but a stronger argument could be made that this question is silly. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja OK, so I fixed that and made it even harder :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most performant would be to define a `static char conversionTable = {0x00, 0x01, ...}`. You simply place the `A` in `a`'s spot the ASCII list, ... and finally `z` in `Z`'s spot.  Then the conversion becomes:

```
char original;
char converted;

converted = converionTable[original];
```

This would cost only 256 bytes of memory, and conversion is damn fast because it's nothing more than a single indexed table access.

Theoretical note: If I'm right, the C standard does not guarantee the use of ASCII as character representation.  If that's indeed the case, the problem would still be solvable, but would become a larger mess. A table would not work.

Comment: I have not been seen table like tab = [1,2,3, ...]? i have seen only table like this tab = {1,2,3, ...}.

And yes - i'm using ASCII.

Comment: @Arlic I made a mistake, it's of course `{1, 2, 3, ... }` to initialize an array. What do you think about this solution?